# Remove given number of records in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have Too much records in my Collection, can I have only desired number of records and remove others without any condition?

I have a collection called Products with around 10,0000 of records and its slowing down my Local application, I am thinking to shrink this huge amount of records to something around 1000, How can do it?

OR

How to copy a collection with limited number of records?

Comment: on what basis you will filter out  1000 document that you want to keep ?

Comment: If you know your filter condition you can use remove() http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/

Comment: @Sumeet I have no condition for removing these records, just want to overcome from excessive overhead on my App.

Comment: i have updated one solution , it may be use full . Just copy it to new collection with limited record and remove old one . But be careful you are removing documents , once deleted can't be rollbacked

Comment: I think the more important question here is: why is only 100,000 records slowing down your database?

Comment: Very true Sammaye . He is a novice user , so that's why i  did not wanted  to go into performance issue . Thanks for asking good question @Sammaye

Comment: @Sammaye I have MongoDB as backend for Django project, whenever I go to products datatable it takes long time to load that page.

Comment: Do you have the correct indexes on that collection, also are you showing all 100,000 products on that page? I assume this page is a paginated list of products right?

Comment: this page is not paginated yet, thats why needed solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy collection with limited number of records without any filter condition, for loop can be used . It copies 1000 document form originalCollection to copyCollection.

```
db.originalCollection.find().limit(1000).forEach( function(doc)
                              {db.copyCollection.insert(doc)} );
```

Comment: That was really helpful.. I don't know why other people were trying to be smarter here..